# Unpredictable abortive shutdown on client side

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, tcp, winsock2

I'm working with a fairly basic server/client setup, where both are located on the same network. They communicate via Winsock2 **blocking** sockets over TCP/IP, and are doing so perfectly fine.

However, for the scenario described below, the client *sometimes* sees an abortive connection termination (RST). It goes right roughly 99 out of 100 times, but that last time annoyingly fails some tests and therefore, my whole build. It is completely unpredictable when and where it happens, and so reproducing the problem has so far eluded me.

If I understand the [the relevant MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) correctly, the nominal connection termination sequence for **blocking** sockets can be summarized as:

```
Client               |  Server
-----------------------------
shutdown(SD_SEND)    |  
                     |  send() response data
i=recv() until i==0  |  shutdown(SD_SEND) 
closesocket()        |  closesocket()
```

In my setup it is necessary to

1. do a relatively expensive operation (let's call it `expensive_operation()`) depending on whether a portion of the received data (let's say, 512 bytes) contains a trigger value. The server is single-threaded, so `expensive_operation()` effectively stops `recv()`ing the data stream until `expensive_operation()` is complete
2. initiate a server shutdown sequence if the client sends a particular sentinel value, let's call it `0xDEADBEEF`.

My **client** is implemented such that the sentinel value is always sent *last*, so after sending it, no other data is sent:

1. `send( "data data data 0xDEADBEEF" )` to server
2. `shutdown(SD_SEND)`  **<------- FAILURE OCCURS HERE**
3. `recv()` until 0 bytes received
4. `closesocket()`

Whenever the **server** receives `0xDEADBEEF`, it confirms the shutdown request and continues termination:

1. `recv()` 512 bytes of data or until 0 bytes are returned
2. Check for trigger. If a trigger is found, perform `expensive_operation()` and go back to step 1, otherwise continue
3. Check for sentinel value. If sentinel is not found, go back to step 1.
4. If the sentinel is found:

   1. `send( confirmation )` to client
   2. `shutdown(SD_SEND)`
   3. `closesocket()`
   4. all the normal server shutdown stuff

I can understand that if the client intends to send *more* data after the sentinel, this will result in abortive connection termination -- because the server actively terminates the connection. This is completely expected and by design, and I can indeed reliably reproduce this behavior.

However, in the nominal case, the sentinel is **always** last in the sequence, which indeed **always** happens as evidenced by the relevant log entries, and indeed graceful connection termination happens as expected most of the time. But **not always**...

As I said, it happens randomly and sporadically, so I can't produce a code snippet that reliably reproduces the problem. The only thing that's consistent is that the failure always occurs when calling `shutdown()` in the client...

I suspect it's more of a design flaw, or some synchronization issue I'm not handling yet, rather than a problem with the code (although I'd be happy to provide the relevant code snippets).

So is there anything obvious I'm overlooking here?

Comment: "do a relatively expensive operation (let's call it expensive_operation()) depending on whether a portion of the received data (let's say, 512 bytes) contains a trigger value. The server is single-threaded, so expensive_operation() effectively suspends recv()" -> Socket is blocking, right? How can it be suspended?

Comment: @Prabhu, the `recv()` is called with a 512 byte buffer, which makes the function return when this amount has been received, even if there is more data available in the stream. The `expensive_operation()` is executed, and then the loop continues: `recv()` is called again with a 512 byte buffer, the data checked for sentinels/triggers, etc.

Comment: Ahh. Ok. The word 'suspension' confused me. By abortive and graceful terminations you mean client sees RST while server does graceful shutdown? Client will receive RST only of server sent it. And hence not a graceful shutdown, isn't? I mean two sides cannot see differently.

Comment: @Prabhu: not sure if relevant, but in reality: `recv()` is called repeatedly until a total of 4 bytes are received. These 4 bytes are the datapacket's header, containing a packet ID and how many bytes the packet contains. Then `recv()` is called repeatedly until a total number of bytes have been received equal to the packet length. Depending on the data contents, either `expensive_operation()` is executed, or server shutdown sequence, or something else.

Comment: @Prabhu yes, indeed. The client sees RST because the server terminated the connection; reworded my question accordingly.

Comment: Possible for a tcpdump? May be in that sporadic instance, there was some packet from client when actually server had the socket closed? Capture would make few things clear. (I understand its not easily reproducible)..

Comment: @Prabhu I'll set up my CI server to do this whenever it happens. This may take some time though (as in, several days...I don't expect it to happen today, and tomorrow it's national holiday, then there's the weekend...)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can provoke an RST to be sent apart from deliberately doing so at the sending end by means which I will not reveal here:

1. Write to a connection that had already been closed by the peer. After a few attempts this will cause `ECONNRESET.`
2. Close a connection without having read all the already-pending data. This will cause an immediate `ECONNRESET.`

Both of these indicate an application protocol error.

In your case I would get rid of the sentinel. It is redundant. Just shutdown the socket for output, or just close it if you know there is no more data coming in. That sends an entirely unambiguous indication to the peer that there is no more data, without any requirement that the peer be precisely sycnchronized byte-for-byte with the local application, which is a weakness and probable source of this bug in your current code.

You need to post some code to get any more concrete assistance.

Comment: Sadly, I am not in charge of this particular design, so getting rid of the sentinel requires a lot of talking in on the customer...Moreover, there is a difference between sending the sentinel (server shuts down) or just closing the socket (server remains active).

Comment: And, as I said, I'm happy to post some code, but that code will not reproduce the problem...I'll do it anyway. NB: The MSDN site I linked to does mention handling FD_CLOSE signals to get the timings right, but that is only for non-blocking sockets, right? At least, I was under the impression that this is done implicitly when using blocking sockets...

Comment: My bad: I seem to have failed to mention that the error I get occurs when calling the client-side `shutdown()`...not sure if relevant

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis That comes under my first point. The shutdown constitutes a write. The peer had already closed the connection, probably prior to a prior write, but buffering defers detection of the case for a few writes (including shutdown). You have an application protocol error.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce, but I can imagine a use case where client sees abortive termination

```
client           server
send sentinel
                 send confirmation
                 shutdown
                 close socket
shutdown                               => error writing on closedsocket !
```

if client process is preempted just after sending its sentinel, and if server is quick, you can fall in that scenario. This is caused by the fact that server side you immediately close the socket after shutdown without being sure client has done its shutdown. IMHO you should do

```
send( confirmation ) to client
shutdown(SD_SEND)
read until 0 or error
closesocket()
all the normal server shutdown stuff
```

The order is then deterministic for the upper part :

```
client           server
send sentinel
                 send confirmation
shutdown         shutdown
                 recv 0
                 close socket     => cannot happen before client shutdown
recv 0                            => socket may be closed server side but it would be harmless
```

Comment: The peer closing his socket does not cause `recv()` to incur an error of any kind, let alone a 'closed socket' error. The local socket isn't closed at all. It casues `recv()` to return zero.

Comment: Indeed, this is something I thought of as well. To try and prevent that scenario, I set a 5 second grace time on the socket closure (SO_LINGER option), so that any premature server-side `closesocket()`  would very certainly not cause client-side `recv()` to fail. Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis There is no need for sleeps in correctly written networking code, and fiddling around with the mostly misused `SO_LINGER` option is not the solution to this problem, or any other problem I have ever seen.

Comment: @EJP, nope, but I was getting desperate :)

Comment: Also, I do not seem to have mentioned that the error occurs when calling client-side `shutdown()`, not on `recv()`...

Comment: @EJP you are right of course : -1 only occurs if *local side* is closed. Thank you for the fix.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis : I was riding a wrong horse because as said by EJP recv would never cause an error in that case. But I think I found where the problem is : see edited post.